# Output Hive table is bucketed but Spark currently does NOT populate bucketed output which is compatible with Hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive, bucket

I have a Apache Spark(v2.4.2) dataframe, I want to insert this dataframe into a hive table.

```
df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([["c1",21, 3], ["c1",32,4], ["c2",4,40089], ["c2",439,6889]]).toDF(["c", "n", "v"])
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
```

And I created a hive table:

```
 spark.sql("create table if not exists sample_bucket(n INT, v INT)
 partitioned by (c STRING) CLUSTERED BY(n) INTO 3 BUCKETS")
```

And then I tried to insert data from dataframe `df` into `sample_bucket` table:

```
 spark.sql("INSERT OVERWRITE table SAMPLE_BUCKET PARTITION(c)  select n, v, c from df")
```

Which gives me an error, saying:

```
 Output Hive table `default`.`sample_bucket` is bucketed but Spark currently 
 does NOT populate bucketed output which is compatible with Hive.;
```

I tried couple of ways which didn't work, on of them is:

```
 spark.sql("set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict")
 spark.sql("set hive.enforce.bucketing=true")
 spark.sql("INSERT OVERWRITE table SAMPLE_BUCKET PARTITION(c)  select n, v, c from df cluster by n")
```

But no luck, can anyone help me!

Comment: Can you share your spark version?

Comment: @Ajay_SK, Spark v2.4.2

Comment: Is it not worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

Spark (current last 2.4.5) does not fully support Hive bucketed tables.
You can read bucketed tables (without any bucket effect) and even insert into it (in this case buckets will be ignoted and futher Hive reads can have unpredicted behaviour).

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19256